# launchd running php script fails under Catalina on exec diskutil

Tags: terminal, catalina, bash, launchd, php

I have a php script that worked perfectly under Mojave from the terminal and as a launchd job. After changing to Catalina, the php script continues fine from the terminal, but the launchd job fails on Catalina.

EDIT 1:

I am suspecting the tightened up security requirements on Catalina, and have added certain programs to Full Disk Access and Accessiblity, but that has not helped.

Here is a simplified version of the script only having essential functions to illustrate the issue:

```
<?php

echo 'begin test', "\n";

isMounted( 'FLASH', $disk_id, $mountedState);
echo 'disk_id=', $disk_id, ' isMounted=', $mountedState, "\n";

function isMounted($volume, &$disk_id, &$mountedState)
{
    $disk_id = exec("diskutil list|grep $volume|awk '{print $6}'", $output, $ret_var);
    if ($disk_id)
    {
        $mountedState = exec("diskutil info $disk_id |grep Mounted|awk '{print $2}' ", $output, $ret_val);
    }
}
```

Here is output from the script when run from the terminal:

```
begin test
disk_id=disk2s1 isMounted=No
```

Here is output as a launchd job (from within test function of Lingon X):

```
begin test
```

It appears that the exec of diskutil fails, with no output. There is also no output to stderr.

Here is the plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PATH</key>
        <string>/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/jas/Keybase.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:/usr/local/sbin</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>test2-php</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/php</string>
        <string>/Users/jas/Websites/RepHunter/cron/test2.php</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Volumes/Backup1/RH-backup/dbtemp/test1-stderr.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Volumes/Backup1/RH-backup/dbtemp/test1-stdout.log</string>
    <key>StartOnMount</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Observations:

1. It appears that the call to exec("diskutil") fails in launchd under Catalina.
2. The script works fine from terminal.
3. The script words fine from both terminal and launchd in Mojave.

EDIT 2:

When I posted this question, it appeared that diskutil would not run properly. Today when I ran the same script, it did run as expected. I am thinking that giving either diskutil or some other utility Full Disk Access solved the problem.

My next task involves a much larger script. That script is now also functioning as a launchd job properly due to the same resolution as the test script.

I prefer to debug php using PHPStorm with xdebug. This involves an apache website running on my workstation. I have some batch processes running under launchd that normally run directly within php and not from within the website. For convenience I run them as a web page to allow my normal debugging. However, the lack of Full Disk Access for the testing environment is apparently preventing some functions of a batch script such as executing an external program like diskutil from working.

What I have done so far is give Full Disk Access to a number of system programs, such as httpd. However it is still not working. My question has evolved from "why does diskutil fail under Catalina" to "what programs do I need to give Full Disk Access" to debug as described.

Here is the list of programs I have set to Full Disk Access so far: bash, php, diskutil, httpd, plus some others not related to this project afaik.

The bottom line question is now the following: how do I enable Full Disk Access to get my debugging environment working?

EDIT 3:

It appears that the workaround to this issue is to not debug the script as a web page, but rather to debug from the CLI. This seems pretty straightforward and one method only needs an environment variable. My first attempt at this worked. I did not think of this because years ago I could not get CLI debugging to work and developed the "debug cron job as a web page" method. Easy now to just debug from the CLI.

In any case, Catalina has made development difficult and wasted a lot of my time coming up with workarounds such as this one. I see I am not alone in the opinion.

Comment: Please add the whole php script **and** the launch agent plist (or a link to the files at e.g. github).

Comment: I have revised the question.

Comment: `begin test\n disk_id=disk1s2 isMounted=Yes` is my result with a slightly improved launchagent.plist (stderr/stdout in /tmp)

Comment: Strangely I can confirm that the observation of klanomath agrees with what I see today. Yesterday I ran the test many dozens of times, and it appeared that the script bailed out with no errors shown but with no output from the function that calls diskutil twice. As if it just dies at that point. However, today when I run the exact script (whether stdout is sent to /tmp or to my initial location), it just works. I have no idea why it apparently was crashing yesterday and working today.